# Altering TextInputLayout hint behavior

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I need to alter TextInputLayout behavior in such a way. By default, when user clicks on EditText inside the Layout, hint leaves the text box and goes above. What I need to achieve is: When user clicks on the EditText, hint does not react. It moves when user starts typing, and comes back then EditText is empty.

I have used a custom library with a thing called FloatingEditText but it does not work correctly with RTL layouts. Does anyone know how to achieve that with TextInputLayout or another way working well with right to left?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

With the Material Components Library you can use the `placeholderText` attribute:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:hint="Label"
        app:placeholderText="placeholder"
```

[image]

**Note:** This requires at least the version **`1.2.0`**.

Answer (score 0):

You can type the name to be entered in the Label part and the hint in the Indian part.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Label">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Hey Ömür,

I added hint in the TextInputLayout but it did not help at all. I don't understand neither how it is supposed to prevent hint from going up till user starts typing...